# Delphi - How to register a custom form

Tags: delphi, forms, z-order

D6 Prof.

Because of Z-Order problem I created a new form. I want to register this custom form in Delphi, to I can use it as normal form, and to I can replace my forms with this - to avoid Z-Order problems.

But I don't know, how to do it.

I created the class, but how to register?

How to force Delphi to show it under "New..." menu?

Thanks for your help:
  dd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you added new properties or the like you have to call RegisterCustomModule() within a design-time package to register the form with Delphi. Use RegisterNoIcon to avoid registration in the component palette.

Comment: I tried this.
I have a central package, and I added a unit to it. The unit containing the inherited form (without dfm).
When I registered this form, I saw ALL FORM IN THE PACKAGE - except this...
What I do wrong?

Comment: So this is very interesting.
1. When I maked a new package that hold a form (with DFM), the object repository show it - without the new published properties I added to it.
2. When I use Register in the package, the form vanishing from the repository. WHy???

Comment: You may need to use OTA to add the form to repository: http://www.mustangpeak.net/opentoolsape.htm

Comment: A solution was:
- RegisterPackageWizard, 
- TNewFormWizard

I used TntUnicode registration unit, replaced all things, and it is working now!!!

Thanks: dd

Answer (score 2):

@durumdara, you can use the [object repository](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Object_Repository) from the delphi IDE.

check theses links

- [Working with the Delphi Object Repository](http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_3803.asp?SK=)
- [Using the Object Repository](http://ftp.podgoretsky.pri.ee/ftp/Docs/Delphi/D5/dg/useop.html)
- [Mastering Delphi 6 - Delphi Object Repository (Google books)](http://books.google.com/books?id=YbS3dPcobl8C&pg=PA44&lpg=PA44&dq=Object+Repository+delphi&source=bl&ots=wmYQdeo7ua&sig=ORa8_ZJ94AVBHU_9kpkYhGlIZBQ&hl=en&ei=a_URTNyvF8uwuAeFzLW5AQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBUQ6AEwADgK#v=onepage&q=Object%20Repository%20delphi&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

Right click the form and select "Add to repository..."

Comment: As I see that is not good, because I can choose the Copy later.
I don't want to use copy, I want to use this form as normal form - not copy, inherit from it!